# How to increase the limitation of Jfuzzylogic "rules"?

Tags: fuzzy-logic, jfuzzylogic

iam searching a way around the limitation of fuzzy control language. In the documentation there is a limitation of 10 rules per rule set and 15 rules overall. I would like to increase the overall limit to for example 30 rules overall.

For example ,when i use JFuzzylogic with more then 15 rule set the 16. rule will be ignored.

Any experience with that around?

Comment: Have you figured out a way to do this? I am planning to use jFuzzyLogic for one of my projects, and If it limits the number of rules, my project won't work. Please let me know If you have found a workaround with jFuzzyLogic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about that limitation in JFuzzyLogic or the Fuzzy Controller Language (FCL), but you could try [jfuzzylite](http://www.fuzzylite.com), which is also free and open source, you can import and export controllers from and to FCL without limitation on the number of rules, and it is available at http://www.fuzzylite.com. In addition, you can use QtFuzzyLite to easily create your controllers.